# ORACLE DB-In a situation that few dates data loaded as null for one column&remaining dates with correct data. null should be replace with correct one

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle10g

Below is the scenario,
There is a table called 'test' have data like this

```
column1 column2 column3  
A        null     7/14/23  
A        null     7/15/23  
A        B        7/16/23  
X        null     7/14/23  
X        null     7/15/23  
X        G       7/16/23
```

This how data loaded in table 'test'

Now i have to update the records like below (null should be replace with the data which recently loaded)

```
column1 column2  column3  
A        B        7/14/23  
A        B        7/15/23  
A        B        7/16/23  
X        G        7/14/23  
X        G        7/15/23  
X        G        7/16/23
```

Please help me how can i update the table records
Note- this table doesn't have any primary key

Im expecting oracle plsql techies to give me idea how can i update records without affecting other dates which loaded correctly

Comment: What will you do if another row appears having column1 = X, column2 = H, column3 = 7/16/23? Should the NULL values in column2 be replaced by G, by H or by something else?

Comment: column1 = X will not have other data it will be having same like coumn2 = G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
select column1, first_value(column2) over(partition by column1 order by column3 desc) as column2, column3 
from data
```

as source of the correct data in a MERGE statement.
(at condition you can identify uniquely each row...)